# How to implement function call in R dataframes

Tags: r

I have a dataset of employee details. I want to replace the 'Not Provided' values with 0, and later convert the data type to numeric.

I tried running a loop. But that's giving an incorrect response.

```
NPFunction<-function(salcol){
 df<-salcol
 i=0
 n=nrow(salcol)
 for(i in n){
   if(df=='Not Provided')
     df[i]=0.0
}}

sal$BasePay=NPFunction(sal$BasePay)
sal$BasePay=as.numeric(sal$BasePay)

dataset is as below:
Id  EmployeeName    BasePay
1   Carolyn A Wilson    100000
2   Not provided    Not Provided
3   Joann Anderson  50000

expected result is :
Id  EmployeeName    BasePay
1   Carolyn A Wilson 100000
2   Not provided    0.0
3   Joann Anderson  50000

In the actual result BasePay column is getting dropped and result is:
Id  EmployeeName
1   Carolyn A Wilson
2   Not provided
3   Joann Anderson
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `for` loop. You can use `ifelse`.

```
sal$BasePay <- with(sal, ifelse(BasePay == "Not Provided", 0, as.numeric(BasePay))
```

For replacing all non-numeric values with `0` -

```
sal$BasePay <- with(sal, ifelse(is.na(as.numeric(as.character(BasePay))),
                                0, as.numeric(BasePay))
```

Comment: "Not Provided" is a given character value, not NA. I want to replace this word with 0

Comment: @Priya The previous code would have worked but see the updated simplified code.

Comment: How will this code work if there are multiple validation. Eg if BasePay=="Not Provided" or BasePay is NA, then BasePay should be set as 0. I used the below code.,but its not working:sal$BasePay <-with(sal,ifelse(BasePay =="Not Provided"|is.na(sal$BasePay),0,as.numeric(sal$BasePay)))

Comment: @Priya That's exactly why I had the original answer. I have re-added it to my answer. Try it out and let me know.

Comment: sal$BasePay <- with(sal, ifelse(is.na(as.numeric(BasePay)), 0, as.numeric(BasePay))...This is not working. it's replacing the Not Provided values by random number.

Comment: @Priya That's probably because `BasePay` is being read as `factor` column. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

We don't need to loop over the rows. Can just do an assignment to after changing to `numeric` column.  Note that the `as.character` is not needed if it is already a `character` class (here, we assume that it could be a `factor` column)

```
NPFunction <- function(data, colN) {
      data[[colN]] <-  as.numeric(as.character(data[[colN]]))
      data[[colN]][is.na(data[[colN]])] <- 0
       data
 }

NPFunction(sal, "BasePay")
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
NPFunction <- function(data, colN) {
     colN <- enquo(colN)

     data %>%
         mutate(!! colN := replace_na(as.numeric(!! colN), 0))
  }                 

NPFunction(sal, BasePay)
```

---

Or if we need a compact option

```
sal$BasePay <- as.numeric(replace(sal$BasePay, sal$BasePay == "Not Provided", 0))
```

Comment: "Not Provided" is a given character value, not NA. I want to replace this word with 0

Comment: @Priya I understand that.  When you do `as.numeric`, it automatically convert to `NA` . e.g. `as.numeric(c(1, 2, 3, "Not Provided"))`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can do the following:

```
sal %>% mutate(BasePay = as.numeric(if_else(BasePay=="Not provided","0",BasePay)))
```